# Which is correct: "between me and Larry" or "between Larry and I"?

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, coordinating-conjunctions

Which is correct?

1. I agree with the plan worked up between me and Larry.
2. I agree with the plan worked up between Larry and I.

Comment: In this case, it's *me and Larry* (or *Larry and me*) because you are the objects of the preposition "between".  See [this question on ELL](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/23535/tom-and-i-or-tom-and-me/) for some more details.

Comment: The pro-tip for figuring out which is to remove the other person. Which sounds right: "worked up between me" or "worked up between I"?

Answer (score 0):

Since "between" governs the phrase, the pronoun must be in the objective case; "between Larry and me" is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Who worked up the plan? Larry and I did.

Who was the plan worked up between? It was worked up between Larry and me.

Larry and me is the correct choice.

The sentence feels awkward to me, I would probably say "Worked up by me and Larry"