# "Alex and I" vs. "me and Alex"

Tags: grammaticality, word-order, personal-pronouns, grammatical-case, coordinating-conjunctions

Is it improper to say "me and Person X"?

I always hear it said as "Person X and I", but have personally learned to say "me and Person X".

Is there a difference between the two versions and is one of them incorrect? "Person and I" just sounds more formal to me.

Comment: There are two parts to this question. 1: The difference between "me" and "I", which is indeed a matter of grammar (_He gave it to me and Jack_ v. _Jack and I went to the store_). 2: Placing yourself first/last in such a construction (_me and Jack_ v. _Jack and me_), which is a _convention_, not a grammatical rule, as suggested by Buck Naked below. #1 is indeed an issue of grammar. #2 is not: so while it may be frowned upon to place yourself first, it is not by any means ungrammatical.

Comment: Related: [Which is correct, me and Larry or Larry and I?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/216555/which-is-correct-me-and-larry-or-larry-and-i); [When do I use “I” instead of “me?”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/313/when-do-i-use-i-instead-of-me); [“My friends and I” vs. “My friends and me” vs. “Me and my friends”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1133/my-friends-and-i-vs-my-friends-and-me-vs-me-and-my-friends).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You would use "X and I" if you and X are the subject of the verb.

You would use "X and me" if you and X are the object of the verb.

For example:

"Smith and I *are going* to the store."

"She *gave* the apples to Jones and me."

Comment: Why is one way correct and the other not?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, placing yourself at the beginning is improper grammar. As far as why, I don't know. It just is. To me, it always sounded self-centered to begin a sentence or list of people with myself. I imagine that is the genesis of the rule but I have no idea. It makes someone sound pretty uneducated to do it, though. "Me and Leon" typically followed by "was..." seems pretty common among those with poor grammar.

Comment: Placing oneself at the beginning of a sentence has very little to do with "grammar", it's merely a convention, a question of good manners, bon-ton, politeness... Curiously, "me and Alex" sounds better than "Alex and me", and I'm not sure why this is so.

Comment: ... 'Me and my shadow' certainly does.